# How to Add a Character to an Existing String in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to replace vowels/syllables in words with other text..for example:

Word entered: `program`

Text to replace syllables/vowels with: ab

Result: `pr**ab**ogr**ab**am`

AND if there is a wildcard (*) entered such as:

Word entered: `dog`

Text to replace syllables/vowels with: *b

Result: `d**ob**og`, where * is replaced with the the first vowel in the word, in this case being "o" and then it is replaced after that with the word entered, in this case "b" making "ob" put in before the vowel "o" in dog.

Any ideas? I am trying to accomplish this with for, if, and while loops only.

Comment: huh?  I think you need to describe this algorithm a little better.  Are you replacing syllables?  vowels?  What about words like `tooth` (1 syllable, 2 vowels)...And can you try to re-explain the second example?  I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

`re.sub(r'([aeoiu])', r'ab\1', 'program') -> 'prabograbam'`

`re.sub(r'([aeoiu])', r'\1b\1', 'dog') -> 'dobog'`

or

`re.sub(r'([aeoiu]+)', r'ab\1', 'tooth') -> 'tabooth'`

`re.sub(r'(([aeoiu])[aeoiu]*)', r'\2b\1', 'boat') -> 'boboat`

Comment: I'm trying to do this with for/if/while loops and not imported modules.

Comment: ''.join([ 'ab'+x if x in 'aeiou' else x for x in 'program']) more pythonic than loops

Comment: That works, but can I substited 'ab' and 'program' for user inputted variables and it will work? I tried it and in shell it works, but when I try printing it comes out blank? For example, empty_str.join([first_syl+x if x in 'aeiou' else x for x in word]), then print (empty_str), it results in nothing in idle.